# Getting different number of AWS instances depending on how I count

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3

I am calculating my total number of reserved instance on the basis of `instance_type` and I'm storing this in a dictionary by `instance_type` as a key.

Firstly, I'm finding my all reserved instances by `get_all_reserved_instances()`, then for each instance returned by this, I do this:

```
if each.state != 'retired':
 key = str(each.instance_type)
 res_count[key]+=each.instance_count
```

I'm also calculating total number of instances on the basis of `instance_type`. Firstly, I'm finding my all instances by `get_all_instances()` and then for each `instance_type` I do this:

```
if each.state == 'running':
 key = str(each.instance_type)
 all_count[key]+=1
```

Now for one instance type it returns:

`all_count = 17`

`res_count = 19`

How's it possible that `res_count` is greater than `all_count`?
`res_count` can be equal to `all_count`, if there is no `ondemand` instance, but why this is greater than `all_count`?

Is there any fault of using state or is there another reason?

Comment: Please use a title that more describes the problem. When someone sees the title in a list of questions, it should tell them what the question is about.

Comment: Why don't you print something in each loop, to see which instances they're each counting?

Comment: @Barmar i already printed them. count of all instance types are correct, but only one instance_type gives this.
can a non-retired instance also be not running ? if it is,then i think this is case for this difference.

Comment: I think so. You can stop instances. But that's more a question about AWS than Python.

Comment: That's why I suggested you should print the instance name. Then you can go to the AWS console and see what's different about that instance.

Comment: I am also not confirm about this, so i am asking here for confirmation.

Comment: This isn't the place to ask questions about AWS. Serverfault.com might be better.

Comment: Okay i will on serverfault.com also.

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspicious:

```
res_count[key]+=each.instance_count

# change to since who knows what is in each.instance_count

res_count[key]+=1
#bottom line, keep the 2 count added the same way, we have no way knowing which to use
```

if the reserve_instance is right, we change the way
total_count is calculated

```
if each.state == 'running':
    key = str(each.instance_type)
    #all_count[key]+=1
    # how about changed to
    all_count[key]+=each.instance_count
```

Comment: No, each.instance_count returns the total number of reserved instances of each.instance_type type. If we do +1 only then it does not count number of reserved instances of this type.

Comment: @abc, I updated the post, to change the way total_count is calculated

Comment: No,all_count is correct. Check this for more, how we are traverse all result return by get_all_instances() .
https://github.com/epheph/ec2-check-reserved-instances/blob/master/ec2-check-reserved-instances.py

Comment: @abc, so state not retired means state running plus any other state, if this is right, the first condition should be modified

Comment: i think,if a instance is not running and it is also not retired then in this case res_count can be greater that all_count. But i am not sure about this,thats why i am asking here for confirmation.